# Trouble Converting ElasticSearch Multi-Index Query to NEST Query

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

The following query in Sense returns the results that I'm looking for, however when I convert it to a NEST query, I always receive 0 results. Where am I going wrong?

```
GET /event,meeting,executive,list,call/_search
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "should": [
            {
              "match": {
                "name": "sample query"
              }
            },
            {
              "match": {
                "agenda": "sample query"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "query": {
          "match": {
            "symbol": "SAMPLESYMBOL"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And here is the NEST search descriptor that I'm using that always returns 0 results.

```
return arg.Indices(new[] { "event", "meeting", "executive", "list", "call" })
    .Size(size)
    .Filter(f => f.Query(qu => qu.Match(m => m.OnField("symbol").Query("SAMPLESYMBOL"))))
    .Query(q => q
        .Bool(b => b
            .Should(
                s => s.Match(m => m.Query(query).OnField("name")),
                s => s.Match(m => m.Query(query).OnField("agenda")))));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query that's working in Sense is a [filtered query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-filtered-query.html#query-dsl-filtered-query), whereas in NEST you are executing a query besides a filter.  That could possibly be the issue.

Try this, which should generate the equivalent JSON to the query you are running in Sense:

```
.Indices(new[] { "event", "meeting", "executive", "list", "call" })
.Size(size)
.Query(q => q
  .Filtered(f => f
    .Query(qq => qq
      .Bool(b => b
        .Should(s => s.Match(m => m.OnField("name").Query(query)))
        .Should(s => s.Match(m => m.OnField("agenda").Query(query)))
      )
    )
    .Filter(ff => ff
      .Query(qf => qf
        .Match(m => m.OnField("symbol").Query("SAMPLESYMBOL"))
      )
    )
  )
);
```